# Compare Date range with moment.js

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs, angular-moment

I am trying to get the following output:

[image]

Here is my code:

```js
const start = "12/7/2018";
const end = "10/6/2019";

var startLease = moment(start, "MM/DD/YYYY");
var endLease = moment(end, "MM/DD/YYYY");

var array = [];
var i = 0;
var nextEnd;

while (1 == 1) {
  var nextStart = nextEnd ? (nextEnd.date() > 28 ? nextEnd : nextEnd) : nextEnd || startLease.clone().add(i, 'M');
  nextEnd = startLease.clone().add(i + 1, 'M') > endLease ? endLease : startLease.clone().add(i + 1, 'M');
  if (nextEnd.date() > 28) {
    nextEnd.subtract(1, 'days')
  } else {}

  array.push(nextEnd.diff(nextStart, 'days'));

  if (nextEnd >= endLease) {
    break;
  } else {}
  i += 1
}

console.log(array);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

**Issue:** 
Instead of going from `7th-6th`, it goes from `7th-7th` of every month. I tried .subtract(1, 'days') but that doesn't output the correct values. However, this works for end of the month.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Just curious, why is the start of current lease period same as end of previous lease period. Should they not differ by a day?

Comment: If you are trying to get the number of days between the start (column 1) and the end (column 2), you can do this in vanilla JS pretty easily:  Math.floor( ( new Date("2019-1-30").getTime() - new Date("2018-12-31").getTime() ) / (1000*3600*24) );  // This gets the milliseconds (getTime) between the two dates, then we get days by dividing by the number of ms per day.

Comment: @shmit it depends if payment is at the beginning or end of month. In this case it's the end.

Comment: @NikolajBaer I am using a moment library for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added some logging to your loop and cut it off after one iteration.

Only the first month is wrong for your example, so the issue is your expectation that if you add 1 month to December 7, 2018, you'll get January 6, 2019 (you'll actually get January 7, 2019).

I'm not sure what the condition that leads to subtracting a day is supposed to do.  nextEnd.date() will resolve to the day of the month, which is always less than 28 for your example.

```js
const start = "12/7/2018";
const end = "10/6/2019";

var startLease = moment(start, "MM/DD/YYYY");
var endLease = moment(end, "MM/DD/YYYY");

var array = [];
var i = 0;
var nextEnd;

while (1 == 1) {
  var nextStart = nextEnd ? (nextEnd.date() > 28 ? nextEnd : nextEnd) : nextEnd || startLease.clone().add(i, 'M');
  console.log(nextStart);
  nextEnd = startLease.clone().add(i + 1, 'M') > endLease ? endLease : startLease.clone().add(i + 1, 'M');
  console.log(nextEnd);
  if (nextEnd.date() > 28) {
    nextEnd.subtract(1, 'days')
  } else {}

  array.push(nextEnd.diff(nextStart, 'days'));

  if (nextEnd >= endLease) {
    break;
  } else {}
  i += 1;
  break;
}

console.log(array);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
              while(1==1){
                var nextStart = nextEnd ? nextEnd : startLease.clone().add(i, 'M');
                var tempstart = startLease.clone();
                tempstart.date(1);
                if (startLease.date() < endLease.date() && array.length == 0) {
                    i = -1;
                }
                tempstart.add(i + 1, 'M');

                var days = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30 ,31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
                var year = tempstart.year();
                if ((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0)
                    days[1] = 29;

                if (endLease.date() > days[tempstart.month()]) {
                    tempstart.date(days[tempstart.month()]);
                } else {
                    tempstart.date(endLease.date());
                }

                nextEnd = tempstart > endLease ? endLease : tempstart;

                var diff_sum = nextEnd.diff(nextStart, 'days');

                array.push (diff_sum);

                if (nextEnd >= endLease) {
                    break;
                }
                i += 1
            }
```